# Bash - Iterate trough SQLite3 DB

Tags: bash, sqlite, iteration

quick overview: I got sqlite3 db which contains following structure and data
**Id|Name|Value**
1|SomeName1|SomeValue1
2|SomeName2|SomeValue2
3|SomeName3|SomeValue3
(continuation of SomeValue3 in here, after ENTER)

Problem is with iteration trough "Value" column, I'm using that code:

```
records=(`sqlite3 database.db "SELECT Value FROM Values"`)

for record in "${records[@]}"; do
   echo $record
done
```

Problem is there should three values using that iteration, but it is showing four.
As result I received:

```
1 step of loop - SomeValue1
2 step of loop - SomeValue2
3 step of loop - SomeValue3
4 step of loop - (continuation of SomeValue3 in here, after ENTER)
```

it should end at third step and just show with line break up something like that:

```
3 step of loop - SomeValue3
(continuation of SomeValue3 in here, after ENTER)
```

Any suggestion how I can handle it with bash?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `sqlite3 database.db "SELECT Value FROM Values" | cat -vet`

Comment: Same situation, additionaly it's adding "$" at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on word splitting to populate an array with the result of a command, it's much more robust to use the `readarray` builtin, or read a result at a time with a loop. Examples of both follow, using `sqlite3`'s *ascii* output mode, where rows are separated by the byte 0x1E and columns in the rows by 0x1F. This allows the literal newlines in your data to be easily accepted.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# The -d argument to readarray and read changes the end-of-line character
# from newline to, in this case, ASCII Record Separator

# Uses the `%q` format specifier to avoid printing the newline
# literally for demonstration purposes.

echo "Example 1"
readarray -d $'\x1E' -t rows < <(sqlite3 -batch -noheader -ascii database.db 'SELECT value FROM "Values"')
for row in "${rows[@]}"; do
    printf "Value: %q\n" "$row"
done

echo "Example 2 - multiple columns"
while IFS=$'\x1F' read -d $'\x1E' -ra row; do
    printf "Rowid: %d Value: %q\n" "${row[0]}" "${row[1]}"
done < <(sqlite3 -batch -noheader -ascii database.db 'SELECT rowid, value FROM "Values"')
```

outputs

```
Example 1
Value: SomeValue1
Value: SomeValue2
Value: $'SomeValue2\nand more'
Example 2 - multiple columns
Rowid: 1 Value: SomeValue1
Rowid: 2 Value: SomeValue2
Rowid: 3 Value: $'SomeValue2\nand more'
```

---

1. See [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) for more on why your approach is bad.
2. Since `VALUES` is a SQL keyword, when using it as a table name (Don't do that!) it has to be escaped by double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is the IFS (internal field seperator) in Bash, which the for -loop counts as a new record.

Your best option is to remove the linefeed in the select statement from sqlite, e.g:

```
records=(`sqlite3 database.db "SELECT replace(Value, '\n', '') FROM Values"`)

for record in "${records[@]}"; do
   echo $record
done
```

Alternatively, you *could* change the IFS in Bash - but you are relying on linefeed as a seperator between records.